# Is the Xcode simulator slower when using a newer simulated device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, cpu-speed

I have a fairly old Mac, so I'm trying to find ways that I can speed up the Xcode simulator. I have an assumption that simulating older devices will be faster than newer ones. This assumption comes from the fact that older devices have less powerful processors, so therefore, when simulated, take up less processing time on the Mac. However, I don't actually know if this is true. So will the Xcode simulator run faster if it's simulating an older device?